# Applescript properties with space in their name

Tags: outlook, applescript

Some properties (eg: "current messages" from Microsoft Outlook 2016) have space in their name. I can't save a script like the following with this property as the Applescript editor complains that End of line is expected but an identifier is found.

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"

    set selectedMessages to current messages

end tell
```

What am I missing?

Comment: First: AppleScript worked with multi-termed (with spaces) properties for Outlook 2011. What does the Outlook 2016 dictionary say `current messages` it is a property of? In 2011 it is a prop of application. Finally, what error are you getting?

Comment: Your dictionary is not loaded correctly, this is commonly solved by rebooting your system. If that didn't work look in the console.app to pinpoint the exact problem.

Comment: Just want to add to the comments above, try compile the script without the troubling line so you see that you have the right connection to the library, then open it with cmd-shift + o, and search for "current message".

Comment: @Frank : it is a property of application, just like 2011 version: `**current messages** (list of message, r/o) : The current messages depending on the context.`
The message I have is "`End of line expected, but identifier found`" and the `messages`string is selected.

Comment: @bm842 - I would then take the approach of comment #2

Comment: @bazzie, rebooting did not solve the issue. But restarting Outlook worked (although I already tried this many times previously). So you are right that somehow, the dictionary was not loaded properly (still mono-term property were working fine  !). Still a mystery but thanks for the suggestions.